# Google Plus Activity list 'id' deprecated

Tags: google-plus

I am trying to retrieve the list of activities for a given {user_id} using the following url end points 
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/106125369682295685477/activities/public?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

I am trying to look at the response and the documentation says that id field of an activity is deprecated.

Then how do we identify the uniqueness of a post from google plus if the id field is deprecated. Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The [`id`of an activity](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities#id) hasn't been deprecated and can still be use to uniquely identify a post. This id is also used as parameter in other methods like [comments.list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/comments/list)

What has been deprecated is the [`id` of the activity list](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/list#id). Instead of this field the `etag` field of the activity list response can now be used to check whether it's a new list or a cached response without changes.